# How do you turn on wrapped mode in the NetBeans output console?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7.2

How do you turn on wrapped mode in the console? I'm using NetBeans IDE 6.8
I keep getting the message:

> ...this line is too long, please switch to wrapped mode to see the whole line...

Comment: If you mean wrap mode in the output window then use the right-click context menu, it's in the bottom half of the menu called "Wrap text"

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Right click within the output window -> wrap text(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

Answer (score 7):

In Netbeans 7.2 it is in Tools-Options-Editor-Formatting-Line Wrap (default off).

Comment: That for the editor.  I'm almost certain the question was really about the output window.

Comment: In Netbeans 9 Beta choosing Line Wrap: Anywhere seems to work also in the Output window.